# Unsetting environment variable with an empty name

Tags: environment-variables

For some reason, my system sets an environment variable with no name. This can be seen in the output from `printenv` as a line containing only `=` and causes problems for Python (more specifically the `os.environ` object).

How do I unset this environment variable? Is there any other workaround (e.g. prevent the variable to be set in the first place)?

To reproduce do e.g. `env -i printenv`, or for the Python problem do `env -i = python -c "import os; os.environ.clear()"`

Comment: `exec env -u '' "$SHELL"` will remove it.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: does not work for me, `env: cannot unset ‘’: Invalid argument`

Comment: The `exec bash -c 'exec "$SHELL"'` since `bash` strips that.

Comment: It's a [bug in Python's `posix.unsetenv`](http://bugs.python.org/issue20658). POSIX doesn't mandate compliant OSes to support empty names, but Python should support them on OSes that do.

Comment: There's a bug `env` from GNU coreutils as well, since it can set but not unset a variable with an empty name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Environment variables aren't supposed to have an empty name, so many utilities don't support them.

The `env` command from GNU coreutils supports setting the environment variable with an empty name but not unsetting it. That's a bug.

```
$ env '=wibble' env |grep wibble                                 
=wibble
$ env '=wibble' env -u '' env
env: cannot unset `': Invalid argument
```

Common shells can't unset the empty name either. That's ok, since the empty name isn't supposed to be used as an environment variable, and can't be used as a shell variable. Zsh is the only buggy one in the lot: it pretends to do the job but in fact does nothing.

```
$ env '=wibble' dash -c 'unset ""'
dash: 1: unset: : bad variable name
$ env '=wibble' bash -c 'unset ""'
bash: line 0: unset: `': not a valid identifier
$ env '=wibble' ksh -c 'unset ""'
ksh[1]: unset: : invalid variable name
$ env '=wibble' mksh -c 'unset ""'
mksh: : is read only
$ env '=wibble' posh -c 'unset ""'
posh: unset:  is read only
$ env '=wibble' zsh -c 'unset ""'
$ env '=wibble' zsh -c 'unset ""; env' | grep wibble
=wibble
```

Python, as you've noticed, [bugs out when it finds the empty name for an environment variable](http://bugs.python.org/issue20658).

**Perl** has no such problem, so it may be a solution for you. Note that you have to execute a new shell to use an external process to change the environment.

```
perl -e 'delete $ENV{""}; exec $ARGV[0] @ARGV' "$SHELL" "-$-"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
import os
for k in os.environ.keys():
     print repr(k)
     del os.eniviron[k]
print os.environ
os.environ.clear()
```

I am not sure why a direct `os.environ.clear()`  throws the error, I started the above for loop code to see if I could find the key causing the problem.
Please not that you have to specify `.keys()`, just iterating using `for k in os.environ:` will give an error because you change the dictionary over which keys you are iterating (`.keys()` creates a copy).

Comment: Does not work for me, using ``os.environ`` methods seems to go via the same system calls as e.g. ``env -u``. However it seems to work to simply remove the key from the underlying dictionary. In Python 2: ``if "" in os.environ.data: del os.environ.data[""]``, in Python 3: `if b"" in os.environ._data: del os.environ._data[b""]`.